# Combining unicode and normal font styles

Tags: pdftex, luatex, calligraphy

I'm typing a document which quite heavily relies on script math fonts and a double-stroke 1 for the identity operator, however, text is in Spanish, so I'm using LuaLaTeX for maximum versatility, however, when using it and with the following commands

```
\includepackage{unicode-math}

\mathbb{1}
\mathcal{O}
\hbar
```

[image]

I get the above, however, when using PDFLaTeX with

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bbold}

\mathbb{1}
\mathcal{O}
\hbar
```

This is the result
[image]

And I much prefer this style of calligraphic O and h-bar with horizontal bar. So my question is: Is there a way to use LuaLateX and unicode math but still get what I'd get if I used PDFLaTex?

Comment: please always post a complete small document that makes the output shown, do you really use `\includepackage{unicode-math}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I only included the relevant bits, I didn't think including the article and begin and end document and equation environments would be necessary. And yes, I really do use it when compiling with LuaLateX

Comment: It's always best to include the full code from top to bottom, if short enough. Then we can copy and paste. Anyway, the gist of the problem is that the two compilers are using different fonts. Open the PDFs and look at the list of used fonts. Then, it is a matter of forcing lualatex to use the font used by pdflatex.

Comment: @DDamian I do not know any package that defines a command of that name so how can anyone reproduce your results or test changes?